# Combobox and DisplayMemberBinding Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, combobox

I have searched online and I cannot find a solid answer to my question. It may be because I am not 100% familiar with XAML but...

I want to be able to set a Combo box Datasource via code. Which I have done. However this comboboxs selected value is updated to match the value selected in a listview and when the combobox is edited, the value in the listview is updated as well. I thought this could be done through only binding. I do not want to hard code some 'work around'. As i have already found a solution to that.

XAML CODE:

```
<ListView Name="ActionListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Actions, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FirstListViewSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.View>                
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Command" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Command}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<ComboBox IsEditable="True" Name="CommandCB" ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Command, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

C# CODE:

```
public partial class DetailsView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged {

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private ObservableCollection<ActionObject> myActions;
public ObservableCollection<ActionObject> Actions
{
    get { return myActions; }
    set
    {
        if (myActions != value)
        {
            myActions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Actions");
        }
    }
}

private List<string> myCommands;
public List<string> Commands
{
    get { return myCommands; }
    set
    {
        if (myCommands != value)
        {
            myCommands = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Commands");
        }
    }
}

private string myCommand;
public string Command
{
    get { return myCommand; }
    set
    {
        if (value != myCommand)
        {
            myCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Command");
        }
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public DetailsView()
{
    myCommands = GetCommandObjects().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    myActions = new ObservableCollection<ActionObject>();

    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

private List<CommandObject> GetCommandObjects()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("commands.json"))
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CommandObject>>(r.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

private void MenuItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (ActionListView.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (ActionListView.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        ActionObject _action = myActions.ElementAt(ActionListView.SelectedIndex);
        Command = _action.Command;
    }
}
}


public class ActionObject
{
    public string Command   { get; set; }
    public string Target    { get; set; }
    public string Value     { get; set; }
    public string Comment   { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Previous:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Command, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=ActionListView, Path=SelectedItem.Command, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I had to set the ElementName and Path to match the Listview.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `List<string> Commands` with `ObservableCollection<string> Commands`

Also you should not assign collections again and again. Remove and/or add items from it.

So your code becomes this

```
private ObservableCollection<ActionObject> myActions;
public ObservableCollection<ActionObject> Actions
{
    get 
    {
         if (myActions == null) 
             myActions = new ObservableCollection<ActionObject>();
         return myActions; 
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<string> myCommands;
public ObservableCollection<string> Commands
{
    get 
    {
        if (myCommands == null) 
            myCommands = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        return myCommands; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it to be a list as far as I know.  Unless there is a way to convert. I have a list of objects that are taken from a JSON script.  The json cannot convert List<CommandObject> to ObservableCollection<string>.

myCommands = GetCommandObjects().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

Comment: You can always do `foreach(var item in myList)  Commands.Add(item)` and please try to add in Property rather than its backup field.

Comment: I have changed the code to:
'myCommands = new ObservableCollection<string>(GetCommandObjects().Select(x => x.Name).ToList());'

But I dont see how this answers my question?

Comment: whats the point in the 'backup field' if we are hitting the property directly?

Comment: Does your VS supports this `public ObservableCollection<string> Commands { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();` If yes then change collection properties like this.

Comment: Yes it does, I am using MVS 2017 RC, also where is the OnPropertyChanged event being triggered in all of this.  How is this solving my question? It just seems like code review atm. Which thank you btw.

Comment: Cool, then use that. Then backing fields won't be required.

Comment: also where is the OnPropertyChanged event being triggered in all of this. How is this solving my question? It just seems like code review atm. Which thank you btw